# What exactly is a broadcast intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

What exactly is a broadcast intent? How is it different from a regular intent?
What are the differences between explicit and implicit broadcast intents?

What does the Intent Sniffer application mean when it says 
"the Intent Sniffer tool performs monitoring of runtime routed broadcasts Intents. It does not see explicit broadcast Intents, but defaults to (mostly) unprivileged broadcasts."?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stackoverflow. You asked almost 5 questions in a single post. Try to ask them in separate posts in future.

Comment: sorry, i'll keep that in mind in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadcast intents are intents used to trigger [BroadcastReceivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) having an Intentfilter matching the broadcasted intent.

This is triggered with `Context.sendBroadcast` as opposed to other intents that are often used with `Context.startActivity`.

A broadcast intent could be received by multiple receivers while other intents will be caught by a specific activity (perhaps at the user's choosing).

I guess Intent Sniffer simply listens to all broadcasts it can get its hands on by registering a few receivers with wide intentfilters.